# Is there a way to filter out your own company's IP in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Can you exclude your own public IP? And if there is a way to do that, can you do that via the reports, or just as an ongoing setting (i.e. will only affect future reports).

Comment: You want to know how much time SO-employees spend on SO? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google has an article about [How do I exclude my internal traffic from reports?](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55481).

Comment: Basically it tells you how to set up filters

Answer (score 5):

It helps to track the IP as a [user-defined variable](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57045) from the start - this requires a server-side tweak to insert the visitor's IP address with the Google Analytics tracking code - example w/PHP:

```
pageTracker._setVar('<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>');
```

... you can then filter on the user-defined variable as needed (it's nice to be able to synch analytics activity with activity stored in server logs, too)

Comment: +1 nice one, and analytics help says it does not track ip addresses :)

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude your own IP. You can add it under [filters](https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/filter_list?) (not sure if that link will work).

I don't know if it applies to past data, though. I also don't see anywhere for applying it to reports. If you see your numbers change immediately then I guess it does.

Comment: Agreed filters are the best way to do this. One thing to note is that it doesn't apply to past data and going forward it will completely filter that data out of your profile (including reports) so if for some reason you don't want to lose that data you can create a second profile to apply the filter too.

Comment: To answer your question, it only excludes future traffic.  Google will not give you access to filter by ip due to their privacy clause.  Your best bet is to figure out what of the traffic was your own based on city, or network and assume it out.